# Regex before a colon

Tags: java, regex

I have this string:

```
[Provider].[Provider]=[ProviderArea].&[X12: WALES]
```

I want to grab just the `X12` part.

I tried:

```
(?<=: )\w+(?=\]$)
```

However, this only gets `WALES`.

I also tried:

```
^[^:]+:\s?
```

But this gets the whole string before and including the colon.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You showed what you don't want, but forgot to show what you want. Is it `X12`?

Comment: I am only trying to find X12

Comment: @TomRodd. If you have written the first regex yourself, then it wouldn't be that difficult to come up with the one which is needed. You just have do modify it a little bit. And even your 2nd regex is quite near.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wan't to find word (`\\w+`) between `&[` and `:` then you can use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanisms

```
(?<=&\\[)\\w+(?=:)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
&\[([^:]+): [^]]+\]

&      # a literal &, followed by
\[     # a literal [, followed by
(      # begin capture
[^:]+  # one or more characters which are not a colon
)      # end capture, followed by
:      # a colon and a space (not shown), followed by
[^]]+  # one or more characters which are not a closing bracket, followed by
\]     # a literal ]
```

In a Java string:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("&\\[([^:]+): [^]]+\\]");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

if (m.find())
    // result is in m.group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following regexp \.&\[(.*): .*] and retrieve the group number 1.

```
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\.&\\[(.*): .*]");

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("[Provider].[Provider]=[ProviderArea].&[X12: WALES]");

        String result = null;

        if(matcher.find())
            result = matcher.group(1);

        if("X12".equals(result))
            System.out.print("Good expression");
        else
        System.out.print("not good");
```